# Объединение имён/сущностей в тексте

Tags: python, nlp, естественный-язык, natasha

Я пытаюсь обработать текст так, чтобы при разбивке на токены имена не разделялись. Для этого я хочу добавить между словами подчёркивания - например, из оригинального текста:

```
"Рональд Рейган - 40-й президент Соединённых Штатов"
```

На выходе получить:

```
"Рональд_Рейган - 40-й президент Соединённых Штатов"
```

Один из вариантов, которые заприметил - [natasha](https://github.com/natasha), однако способа изменить текстовую строку с её помощью я не нашёл. Как крайний вариант я хотел сгенерировать размеченный текст и заменить разметку на подчёркивание с помощью re.sub, однако я даже не могу присвоить текст переменной:

```
from natasha import NamesExtractor
import natasha.markup

text = "Рональд Рейган - 40-й президент Соединённых Штатов"

extractor = NamesExtractor()
matches = extractor(text)
spans = [_.span for _ in matches]

markup = natasha.markup.show_markup(text, spans)
type(markup)
>>> NoneType
```

Ни сам matches, ни любой объект, который возможно из него сгенерировать, я не смог перевести в желаемый вид. Я прошёлся по [документации](https://natasha.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/) и оригинальному коду. В теории, его можно адаптировать чтобы получить что-то около того, что мне нужно, но с моим скиллом это займёт очень много времени.

Потому хотелось бы узнать: нету ли более простого способа (с этой или другими библиотеками)?

Comment: А что в `matches`? Нет ли там имен?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В каждом объекте `Match` (элементе списка `matches`) указано начало/конец найденного совпадения в строке (по сути границы среза найденной строки). Нужно взять срез текста с границами указанными в `Match`, заменить пробел на подчеркивание, вставить в исходный срез текста.

```
from natasha import NamesExtractor, MorphVocab

text = "Рональд Рейган - 40-й президент Соединённых Штатов."

morph_vocab = MorphVocab()
extractor = NamesExtractor(morph_vocab)
matches = extractor(text)

# Преобразовываем строку в список, чтобы можно было заменять срезы
text_list = list(text)

for match in matches:
    replacement = text[match.start:match.stop].replace(' ', '_')
    text_list[match.start:match.stop] = replacement

print(''.join(text_list))
```

Вывод:

```
Рональд_Рейган - 40-й президент Соединённых Штатов
```

Если будет замена строку другой длины (например, пробел заменяется на несколько подчеркиваний, или наоборот пробелы вообще убираются), то при нескольких совпадениях данный алгоритм будет работать некорректно, т.к. при каждой замене длина списка символов будет изменяться, а индексы начала/конца совпадений будут оставаться теми же. Для устранения этой проблемы, как вариант, можно обрабатывать список совпадений от последнего к первому (цикл заменить `for match in reversed(matches):`).

Comment: Красиво решили через срезы :)

Comment: Спасибо, отлично решение!

Comment: Актуализировал код в ответе с учетом изменений в библиотеке natasha

Answer (score 0):

как вариант с регуляркой.
тоже вроде работает:

```
from natasha import NamesExtractor, MorphVocab
from re import sub

text = "Рональд Рейган - 40-й президент Соединённых Штатов."

morph_vocab = MorphVocab()
extractor = NamesExtractor(morph_vocab)
matches = extractor(text)

for m in matches:
    text = sub(fr'({m.fact.first})(\s)({m.fact.last})', r'\1_\3', text)
    
print(text)

#
Рональд_Рейган - 40-й президент Соединённых Штатов.
```